# How to resolve a variable for char length?

Tags: c, arrays, variables, char

EDIT

i want to create a program which will work with a long number. the user will be asked to input the length (in digits) of the number they want to work with. there is a

```
char aa [the chosen length goes here];
```

where in the [] brackets should be the value that was input by the user.
it could look like this:

"please input the length in digits"
there is a scanf and you input, for example, 17
then a char aa [17] is created

i just don't know how can i use a variable to input a value in the [] brackets defining the memory size that is saved for a char

Comment: i am sorry for not being clear, i meant that the user would chose the number that goes into the [] brackets

Comment: What is `length` ? Edit your question in order to clarify instead of posting comments.

Comment: I think this `scanf("%d", &length);` should be `scanf("%d", &digit);`

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You get a `length` from the user and then you use `digit+1` as the length, even though `digit` is undefined. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What exactly is it that you want @lenka? Do you want your user to type in how big he wants the char array to be?

Comment: `digit`? `length`? `aa`? Please be consistent!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic array using ANSI C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338431/dynamic-array-using-ansi-c)

Comment: That's called variable length array. Possible according to c99. See my answer

Comment: A VLA is standard C. You did not a bit of research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a variable lenght array, you can do it like this:

```
int digit;
scanf("%d", &digit);
char test [digit+1];
```

This will work for your purposes. Usual restrictions of course apply.
Keep in mind this functionality was only added in the C99 Standard. So if your compiler supports only previous standards, this will not work.

However, the more appropriate and better practice method to use is to use `malloc` to allocate the char array properly

```
int digit;
scanf("%d", &digit);
char* aa = malloc(digit + 1);
//Do what you want with the char array aa
free(aa);
```

Do not forget to check the result of `malloc()` against `NULL` and free the variable afterwards to prevent memory leaks if you want to do this.

Also be aware that the "array" `malloc` returns is actually just a pointer, which is very relevant when trying to determine the size/length of it, using `sizeof`:

```
char real_array[5];
sizeof(real_array); // == 5

char* dynamic_array = malloc(5);
sizeof(dynamic_array) // == sizeof(char*) == on most systems = 8
```

Comment: I suggest to also warn about the different behavior regarding `sizeof(array)`, when using a dynamic allocated memory. (Not sure to just edit your answer, since this is not completely relevant to the question.

Comment: @Superlokkus feel free to edit my answer if you feel that needs adding.

Comment: Done. Hope it will get pass the peer review.

Comment: thanks, i will check how it works straight away but it seems like it could work for me

Comment: thank you, this works perfectly for me

Comment: This is not a _dynamic_ array, but a variable length array. Once defined, you cannot change its length.

Comment: @Olaf Semantics, but you're right. I'll change it.

Comment: @Magisch: Semantics are the reason we use specific words and it is clear what the other means. Otherwise we still would have to point at that thing with the four things and the other thing for eating.

Comment: @Olaf I understand, I corrected it already and admitted you're right. I just sometimes mix up semantics in english.

Comment: @Magisch: Leo ist da sehr hilfreich;-) Nur nicht gleich den ersten Treffer nehmen.

Comment: Makes me wonder who Leo is :)

Answer (score -1):

What you are asking is variable length array which is possible in C99. See [Dynamic array allocation on stack in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441916/dynamic-array-allocation-on-stack-in-c)

Look at the following code snippet:

```
int size;
scanf("%d", &size);
char array[size + 1];  //1 extra space to accommodate `\0` character

printf("%d\n", sizeof(array));
```

This will print `sizeof(char) * (size+1)` proving the array creation dynamically.

The only disadvantage of this way over `malloc` way is after declaring an array (which is of user-input size) you can't change the array size in program. It's fixed.

While using dynamic memory allocation (`malloc`, `calloc`) you can change the array size whenever possible in a program by `free`ing the memory.

Since variable length array is possible in c99 you may have to use `gcc --std=c99 -c program.c` to compile your source code. For other compiler refer the proper compiler manual.

Comment: when i input a value, the output is the value times 4 so this cannot be right

Comment: Also you don't have to wonder to get downvoted, when just posting a stub and then editing it after reading significant facts from the other answers.

Comment: @lenka: what did you enter? If you enter `5` then you will get `20` as `sizeof(int)` is most probably `4` (machine dependent). So what you get is sizeof(array) which is = `sizeof(member) * array_size`

Comment: @Superlokkus: Even if that "stub" contains the gist of answer?

Comment: Also your answer IMHO didn't really targeted the question, but rather just throw a solution without any context.

Comment: I downvoted this because it didn't answer the question. Now that it does answer the question, I'm leaving the downvote, so you have a reason to post a good answer from the start, instead of posting a very bad answer then improving it.

Comment: A VLA is not a _dynamic_ array. The reason is given exactly in your text.