# How can I initialize an array in C language when I am not sure what its length will be and the printf statement is not giving the correct output?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop, iteration

I am writing a program in C after learning the basics to so I am a noob. In my program, I have an array that I declared as a global array, but I have to take its input through iteration. The number of elements of that array depends upon the user giving input.

How can I initialize an array when I am not sure what its length will be, and I am taking input through iteration? I want the scope of that array to be global so that I can use it further in my program.

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nos_wl; i++)
    {
item_no = item_no + 1;
printf("Item-%d Details:\n", item_no);
printf(" Item cost%d: $", item_no);
fflush(stdin);
scanf(" \n%.2lf", &item_cost[i]);
    }
for (int i = 0; i < nos_wl; i++)
    {
printf("%.2lf\n", item_cost[i]);
    }
```

In my code, `nos_wl` is the number of elements the user wants to enter in the array `item_cost[]`, which is a double type array.

Also, I don't know why, the last printf statement is not giving the output expected, it gives a very large decimal number.

Comment: Use dynamic memory allocation, `malloc`, `realloc` and friends. Read a C book/tutorial and do a search as there are countless examples out there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic array using ANSI C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338431/dynamic-array-using-ansi-c)

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour. Please don't do that, and don'r learn from web sites that tell you to do that. Only output streams can be flushed. Also please align your code properly.

Comment: `scanf(" \n%.2lf", &item_cost[i]);` is incorrect, please use `scanf("%lf", &item_cost[i]);` and also check what value the function returns which should be `1`. Suppose `nos_wl` is `2` and you input `1.234 5.678` then your code would take `1.23` for the first input and `4` for the second, leaving `5.678` unread.